# Exception to redirection with htcaccess

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Hey I have these in my htcaccess to redirect everything to my homepage :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content [NC]
RewriteRule .* / [L,R=301]
```

I want to test a new page on mywebsite.com/test

So I've added this to htcaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test|test/.*)$
RewriteRule .* / [L,R=301]
```

But my page mywebsite.com/test stills redirect to my homepage.

Anyone could help me out here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change 
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test|test/.*)$`

To
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test$`

Without more detailed information about the exact behavior you desire and the behavior you are seeing, it is difficult to provide a more precise answer but in short, my suggestion is a slightly more terse way to say "don't redirect anything that starts with "/test".

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Alas, still not yelding the expected results.

I want to access my test page which url is mywebsite.com/test . Atm with your change it still redirects to mywebsite.com

Comment: It sounds like there may be some other rule overriding your .htaccess. Are you sure you're running Apache? Can you enable [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog).

Comment: You must be right, there must be a conflict with my wordpress settings. When I remove all the redirection in htcaccess, I get 404 when typing mywebsite.com/dqzdzqdzqd. But when I type mywebsite.com/test it redirects to my homepage. Dont know why tho...

Comment: Yes, try disabling all plugins as well and then install and activate the following two plugins https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/ along with https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-rewrite-rules/. Using these two plugins you can see what rewrite rules are defined and even test them right in the plugin. Although I'm happy to help, I do ask that  you follow my instructions so that I can, hopefully, provide an answer and get credit for it.

Comment: Yes thanks ted. I feel a bit idiotic : I clear'd cache and tried again and it's working... Browser was using a cached version of htcaccess or something.... I'll edit post.

Comment: Yes, caching can interfere with debugging these types of situations. Good idea. In the future you can also try testing in a private browser window to minimize the possibility of the cache interfering. Good luck!